# How to speed up agregate queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregate

I am running examples of aggregate queries similar to this:

https://www.compose.com/articles/aggregations-in-mongodb-by-example/

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  { 
    { $match: {"nested.field": "1110"}}, {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $sum: "$nested.field"
      },
      average_transaction_amount: {
        $avg: "$nested.field"
      },
      min_transaction_amount: {
        $min: "$nested.field"
      },
      max_transaction_amount: {
        $max: "$nested.field"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

One collection that I created have 5,000,000 inserted big JSON documents (around 1,000 K->V pairs, some are nested).

Before adding index on one nested field - it takes around 5min to do count of that field.
After adding index - for count it takes less than a second (which is good).

Now I am trying to do SUM or AVG or any other like example above - it takes minutes (not seconds). 
Is there a way to improve aggregate queries in MongoDB?

Thanks!

Comment: [Get a bigger boat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=We%27re%20Gonna%20Need%20a%20Bigger%20Boat). Whilst you are doing what you can you have optimal "query" selection, the sheer process of crunching a lot of data takes considerable time. Far more than a query planner takes to evaluate how many results match an index ( particularly when that's all in memory).

Comment: Ok.. I am running similar query on MySQL (sum) for any column and it takes less than few seconds on 5M records.. I understand that can not easily do nested JSON in MySQL (or at least is not that fast) but was expecting better performance with Mongo for this case.. Or maybe there are some other tweaks? (I am getting random JSON from customers so do not have control on how it will look like before it comes to me but need to store and index few fields)..

Comment: Depending on how static your data is you could perhaps run this query every X and insert the results onto the documents.

Comment: *" understand that can not easily do nested JSON in MySQL (or at least is not that fast)"* -- So it's not really a "similar query" at all is it? Perhaps you actually should try something that is similar, being values in a "flat" property that is indexed.  In all honesty the question is far too broad. There can be many reasons and many different approaches to improving performance, ranging from re-design to scaling up or scaling out. If all you are doing is bench-marking one operation ( that already is not exactly the same ) against a different database then it's also too broad.

Comment: How can I redesign JSON that is coming to me for which I have no control over and can be any number of fields, any number of nested fields and any structure? And any new JSON is different.. All I get is JSON and path to what fields should be indexed (when is nested). Also - what are the rules for start scaling out or up? Is 5M records too much for 1 modern machine (e.g. 8 CPU, 64GB) running MongoDB for aggregate queries? Raw data size is about 6GB.

Comment: Is there a date field in the documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, group currently does not use indexes in mongodb. Only sort and match can take advantage of indexes. So the query as you wrote it is as optimized as it could be.

There are a couple things you could do. For max and min, you could just query them instead of using the aggregation framework. You can than sort by $nested.field and take just one. You can put an index on $nested.field and you can then sort ascending or descending with the same index.

If you have any control over when the data is inserting, and the query is as simple as it looks, you could keep track of the data yourself. So you could have a table in mongo where the collection has the "Id" or whatever you are grouping on and have fields for "total" and "sum". You could increment them on inserts and then getting the total and averages would be fast queries. Not sure if that's an option for your situation, but its the best you can do.

Generally, mongo is super fast. In my opinion, the only place its not quite as good as SQL is aggregation. The benefits heavily outweigh the struggles to me. I generally maintain separate reporting collections for this kind of situation as I recommended.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer on 'how to' with Mongo. Will try some of these recommendations..